# correlation heatmap in bokeh python

Tags: python, bokeh

Tried looking around a bit for finding a simpler way to plot the correlation matrix in bokeh via heatmap; however could not find much help.

Let's say i have a correlation DF created by way of :

```
 corr_df = df.corr()
```

Can you please assist how I can use the continuous number range in this df to reflect the color intensity in bokeh?
I understand for the X and Y columns i will first have to pull those unique column names in a factors list.

```
factors = ["A","B","C"]
x = ["A","A","A","B"]
y = ["A","B","C","C"]
```

Is there a easy peasy way to do all of this ?
I can do all of this in seaborn with just a single line function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python bokeh, how to make a correlation plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191653/python-bokeh-how-to-make-a-correlation-plot)