# Bokeh heatmap from Pandas confusion matrix

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, confusion-matrix

How can a Pandas `DataFrame` be shown as a Bokeh heatmap?

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#heat-maps shows some example, but trying to modify always only gave an empty plot.

Example confusion matrix:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[10, 0, 1], [1, 10, 0], [1, 1, 9]], 
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                  index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.index.name = 'Treatment'
df.columns.name = 'Prediction'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First import packages and prepare data.frame :

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import BasicTicker, ColorBar, LinearColorMapper, ColumnDataSource, PrintfTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import transform

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[10, 0, 1], [1, 10, 0], [1, 1, 9]],
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C'],
    index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.index.name = 'Treatment'
df.columns.name = 'Prediction'
```

To use my solution you have to *stack* the data.frame :

```
# Prepare data.frame in the right format
df = df.stack().rename("value").reset_index()
```

Now, we can create the plot :

```
# here the plot :
output_file("myPlot.html")

# You can use your own palette here
colors = ['#d7191c', '#fdae61', '#ffffbf', '#a6d96a', '#1a9641']

# Had a specific mapper to map color with value
mapper = LinearColorMapper(
    palette=colors, low=df.value.min(), high=df.value.max())
# Define a figure
p = figure(
    plot_width=800,
    plot_height=300,
    title="My plot",
    x_range=list(df.Treatment.drop_duplicates()),
    y_range=list(df.Prediction.drop_duplicates()),
    toolbar_location=None,
    tools="",
    x_axis_location="above")
# Create rectangle for heatmap
p.rect(
    x="Treatment",
    y="Prediction",
    width=1,
    height=1,
    source=ColumnDataSource(df),
    line_color=None,
    fill_color=transform('value', mapper))
# Add legend
color_bar = ColorBar(
    color_mapper=mapper,
    location=(0, 0),
    ticker=BasicTicker(desired_num_ticks=len(colors)))

p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')

show(p)
```

*Note : I use a more complete solution than just call `HeatMap` from the bokeh library because 1) you have more control on parameters like this, 2) there are lot of incompatibilities with Bokeh, Pandas, etc and this is the only solution working with my configuration.

Comment: Merci beaucoup! It seems like `HeatMap` is missing from the latest bokeh and this is the recommended solution (same as in the question's link).